# django-taggit tag length increase problem

Tags: django, django-taggit

I use django-taggit in my django app.

Is there a way to increase the tag length limit?
I get errors that I passed my tag length limit.

Thanks, Alex

Comment: I just specified `MAX_TAG_LENGTH = integer` and everything works properly. I think that if You write here some of Your traceback it will be easier to find solution.

Comment: Cris, post as an answer get karma.

Comment: I had added the `MAX_TAG_LENGTH` inside the settings file. But it doesn't work as expected. Can you please mention any additional things I am missing here?

Comment: ok..got it..I had to rollback and reapply migrations